# V8 Debug Protocol Commands

Tags: javascript, debugging, v8

could you send me to a website or give me all the available commands of the V8 debug protocol, and explain me how they work.

I'm speaking about commands like setbreakpoint, listbreakpoints, backtrace or scope etc..

Thanks :)

--

EDIT :

It's the best i've find for now :

- https://github.com/dtretyakov/node-tools/wiki/Debugging-Protocol
- https://github.com/buggerjs/bugger-v8-client/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation is here [Debugging over the V8 Inspector Protocol](https://v8.dev/docs/inspector)

Comment: Thanks, i find that : https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Debugger/ It's a good start, but maybe it's too connected to chrome, because i want the base commands of v8. What do you think ?

Comment: The inspector protocol is the same for Chromium as for any other embedder, so it's not "too connected to Chrome". This documentation is the authoritative list of the inspector commands that V8 supports.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I need an example in c++. Do you have?